# JQuery Wait for Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, loops

I have the following code:

```
    for (i=1;i<=pages;i++) {
        $('#procout').append(Processing Page#"+i+"<br />");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'processor.php',
            data: {storen: perpage, pagen : i},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#procout').append(data+"<br />");

            }
        });
    }
```

What I am trying to do is make the script wait for the Ajax response after every loop. Instead it prints out the "Processing Pages" lines all together and the the Ajax responses from each run in the order the server responds (out of order). I tried setting the async option to false, but that simply causes the JS to wait until all six requests are done and then output everything from all runs together.

Note: The values of the pages, perpage, and pagen are irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: You should do some searching on "ajax queue" and "jquery ajax queue plugin" as it looks like this is what you desire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've already tried making the ajax requests `async:false` (which is seldom if ever a good idea anyway), consider breaking your loop body into a function that makes the ajax request, and then runs the next request in the callback:

```
function runRequest(num){
    if (num > pages) return; //since your original was looping while i <= pages

    $('#procout').append("Processing Page#" + num + "<br />");
    $.ajax({
       url: 'processor.php',
       data: {storen: perpage, pagen : num},
       success: function(data) {
           $('#procout').append(data + "<br />");

           runRequest(num + 1);
       }
    });
}
```

And then of course starting the process off with

```
runRequest(0);
```

Comment: The loop never ends... I even added pages as a variable to be passed on to the function and checked its value. Could the recursion be causing that? What if I kept my loop and passed the processing to this function on each run?

Comment: The function should work.  Are you sure your calling `runRequest(num + 1)` in the callback?  If by chance you wrote `runRequest(num++)` that will **not** work.

Comment: Yes, I used your code as in and ensured that it knew the value of "pages" correctly. Let me see if I build this in jsfiddle and provide you with a link

Comment: Adam, I figured it out. I had added the pages variable in the call to the runRequest() function in the original call... but forgot to add it to the recursive call. Somehow that was causing recursion to keep running.